# How to print pointer contents in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, unsafemutablepointer

I am trying to print contents of pointer pointed to by a raw pointer but when I print or NSLog, I get the value of pointer than the contents of memory pointed to by pointer. How do I print contents of memory pointed to by pointer? Below is my code:

```
    let buffer = unsafeBitCast(baseAddress, to: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt32>.self)
     for row in 0..<bufferHeight
    {
        var pixel = buffer + row * bytesPerRow

        for _ in 0..<bufferWidth {
           // NSLog("Pixel \(pixel)")
            print(pixel)
            pixel = pixel + kBytesPerPixel
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pixel` is a pointer to an `UInt32`, in order to print the pointed-to
value you have to dereference it:

```
print(pixel.pointee)
```

Note that incrementing a pointer is done in units of the stride of
the pointed-to value, so your

```
pixel = pixel + kBytesPerPixel
```

will increment the address by `4 * kBytesPerPixel` bytes, which
may not be what you intend.

Comment: Ok I replaced UInt32 with UInt8, so the pointer is now UInt8 *. How do I typecast this UInt8* pointer to UInt32 * and then print integer?